# How to add Links of Google Play store as well as Samsung app store in “Rate This App” & " More Apps" option

Tags: android

I have publish my app on play store as well as samsung galaxy app store, today samsung has rejected my app because i have given my app has two option one is "Rate Us" & "More Apps From Developer" if anyone click on this options its open in Google Play not in samsung app store, so i want to know how can i add both app store link in one code

this is my more apps code

```
else if (id == R.id.nav_more) {
        try {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=my+apps"); // missing 'http://' will cause crashed
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
```

& this is Rate The App code

```
public void rateUsOnPlayStore() {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + this.getPackageName());
    Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    // To count with Play market backstack, After pressing back button,
    // to taken back to our application, we need to add following flags to intent.
    goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
    try {
        startActivity(goToMarket);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="  + this.getPackageName())));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The package name of Samsung Galaxy App Store is **com.sec.android.app.samsungapps**, so to open it try the following :

```
  public static void openGalaxyStore(Context context, String packageName) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.samsungapps.com/appquery/appDetail.as?appId=" + packageName);
            Intent goToMarket = new Intent();
            goToMarket.setClassName("com.sec.android.app.samsungapps", "com.sec.android.app.samsungapps.Main");
            goToMarket.setData(uri);
            try {
                context.startActivity(goToMarket);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```